GPS functionality not working after packaging Electron app with serialport and @serialport/parser-readline
I'm developing an Electron app that uses the serialport and @serialport/parser-readline packages to read GPS data from a USB device. The GPS functionality works perfectly when I run the app in development mode using electron .. However, after packaging the app using electron-builder and installing it on the same machine, the GPS functionality does not work.
I've checked the serial port settings and ensured that the device is properly connected, but the app is not able to read any GPS data. I've also tried running the packaged app with administrator privileges, but that didn't make a difference.
Here are the packages I'm using:
serialport: ^9.2.5
@serialport/parser-readline: ^1.0.0
And here's my code snippet for initializing the GPS:
const serialPort = require('serialport');
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const { parseNmeaSentence } = require('nmea-simple');

let port;
let parser;

// Function to initialize GPS functionality
const initializeGPS = (detectedPort) => {
  logToRenderer('Initializing GPS...');

  // If the port is already initialized and is the same as the detected port, skip initialization
  if (port && port.path === detectedPort) {
    logToRenderer('GPS already initialized, starting data parsing...');
    parser.on('data', (data) => {
      // Parse GPS data and send to renderer
      try {
        const parsedData = parseNmeaSentence(data); // Parse NMEA sentence to extract GPS data
         logToRenderer({ raw: data, parsed: parsedData }); // Log raw and parsed GPS data

        if (parsedData.sentenceId === 'GGA') {
          const latitude = parsedData.latitude;
          const longitude = parsedData.longitude;
          win.webContents.send('gps-data', { latitude, longitude }); // Send GPS data to renderer process
        }
      } catch (error) {
        logToRenderer('Error parsing NMEA sentence: ' + error.message); // Log parsing error
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Initialize the new port
    port = new SerialPort({
      path: detectedPort, // Use the detected port
      baudRate: 57600,
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        logToRenderer('Error opening serial port: ' + err.message);
        return;
      }
    });

    parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));

    parser.on('data', (data) => {
      try {
        const parsedData = parseNmeaSentence(data); // Parse NMEA sentence to extract GPS data

        if (parsedData.sentenceId === 'GGA') {
          const latitude = parsedData.latitude;
          const longitude = parsedData.longitude;
          win.webContents.send('gps-data', { latitude, longitude }); // Send GPS data to renderer process
        }
      } catch (error) {
        logToRenderer('Error parsing NMEA sentence: ' + error.message); // Log parsing error
      }
    });
  }
};

// Function to periodically check for available serial ports
const checkPorts = async () => {
  try {
    const currentPorts = await SerialPort.list(); // Retrieve list of current serial ports
    // logToRenderer('Current Ports: ' + JSON.stringify(currentPorts)); // Log current serial ports
    const currentPortNames = currentPorts.map(port => port.path);
    const previousPortNames = previousPorts.map(port => port.path);

    const addedPorts = currentPorts.filter(port => !previousPortNames.includes(port.path));
    const removedPorts = previousPorts.filter(port => !currentPortNames.includes(port.path));


    if (addedPorts.length > 0) {
      if (addedPorts.some(port => port.manufacturer === 'Prolific')) { // Check if a GPS device is plugged in

        const gpsPort = addedPorts.find(port => port.manufacturer === 'Prolific').path; // Get the path of the GPS device
        initializeGPS(gpsPort); // Initialize GPS functionality with the detected port
      }
    }else{
      // Handle case where no new ports are added but the GPS device is already connected
      const gpsPort = currentPorts.find(port => port.manufacturer === 'Prolific');
      if (gpsPort) {
        logToRenderer('GPS device already connected on port: ' + gpsPort.path);
        logToRenderer('port in if cond: '+ port);
        initializeGPS(gpsPort.path);
      }
    }

    if (removedPorts.length > 0) {
      if (removedPorts.some(port => port.manufacturer === 'Prolific')) { // Check if a GPS device is unplugged
        logToRenderer('GPS device unplugged');
        if (port) {
          port.close((err) => {
            if (err) logToRenderer('Error closing serial port: ' + err.message); // Log error if unable to close serial port
          });
        }
      }
    }

    previousPorts = currentPorts; // Update previous port list with current ports
  } catch (error) {
    logToRenderer('Error listing serial ports: ' + error.message); // Log error if unable to list serial ports
  }
};
setInterval(checkPorts, 10000); // Set interval to check for ports

